# When I Scroll tableview its cell updated automatically How can i stop to update cell?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uikit, tableview

When I Scroll `tableview` its cell updated automatically.

How can i stop to update cell?

My code snippet:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constant.FAV_CAROUSEL_CELL_IDENTIFIER, for: indexPath) as! carouselFavCell

        let objProvider1 = objProvider.providerArr[indexPath.row] as! ProviderModel
        self.providerArr = objProvider.providerArr[indexPath.row] as! ProviderModel
        self.apointmentArr = objProvider1.appointmentArr
        self.serviceArr = objProvider1.serviceArr

        cell.caroudelView.reloadData()

        cell.caroudelView.type = .linear
        cell.caroudelView.tag = indexPath.row

        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = Constant.CELL_BG_COLOR

        cell.caroudelView.backgroundColor = Constant.CELL_BG_COLOR
        cell.lblProviderName.text = objProvider1.providerName

        cell.lblProviderName.textColor = Constant.LBL_TITLE_DARK_GRAY
        cell.lblProviderName.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)

        cell.btnMenu.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "option1.png"), for: .normal)

        cell.buttonAction = { (sender) in
            self.providerArr = self.objProvider.providerArr[indexPath.row] as! ProviderModel
            self.actionPicker()
        }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: when tableview scroll cell can't be update

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the following line:

```
cell.caroudelView.reloadData()
```

Without this line, I guess, the cells will only have the value they get when they first appear.